# I have a function in jQuery and it does not work as expected

Tags: jquery

```
function hideShowTextBox(tabName, index, tabContainer) {
  var tabIndex = index + 1;
  var dropDownId = tabContainer + '_' + tabName + '_IncomeDetails' + tabIndex + '_dpEmploymentStatus';

  //this line gives a blank value..What may be the problem???
  alert($(dropDownId + ' option:selected').text()); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID selectors must begin with the `#` character, e.g.`#foo`. Try:

```
var dropDownId = '#' + tabContainer + '_' + tabName + '_IncomeDetails' + tabIndex + '_dpEmploymentStatus';
```